# Does same hash value indicate a valid key?

Tags: digital-signature

I send a message to someone along with a public key, which they use to hash the message.

If they get the same hash value that I get when I hash the same content with the private key, does that safely imply that they have my public key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because you don't "hash" a message with a public key. You encrypt a message with a public key.

Furthermore, a message encrypted with the public key will never be identical to a message "encrypted" (e.g. the encryption function applied with the private key) with the private key.

You can't really prove if someone has your public key, because a message encrypted with your public key is indistinguishable from random data. Therefore even if B is in possession of a message that can be successfully decrypted by your private key, it can still be argued that B received this binary blob from a third-party without any knowledge of its purpose.

Comment: Aren't public and private key arbitrary for a given key pair and isn't signing something creating a hash?

Comment: Oh, so you can't sign with a public key. It doesn't work!

Comment: @IanWarburton Exactly, because *everyone* has access to the public key, therefore a "signature" with the public key would have no meaning, and the only person who would be able to verify it would be the owner of the private key.

Comment: Could signing with a public key at least show that a message hasn't been tampered with?

Comment: @IanWarburton No, because an attacker can also get access to the public key and create a tampered message that would be just as valid. What you would need to do is create a message, sign that message with your private key and then encrypt that signed message with the recipient's public key. The recipient would then decrypt the message, and then verify the signature with your public key.